# manually allocate data buffer for skb struct

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have two boards that connected via the PCIE bus. They can exchange data via the pre-allocated message buffers. Now I try to implement a virtual network interface based on this connection. 
Referring some network driver sources show that there are two methods they implemented the receive path:

- Use `dev_alloc_skb()` to allocate the `skb` inside the receive function and copy the data to the buffer allocated for this `skb`.
- Use `dev_alloc_skb()` to allocate the `skb` and put their buffers into the RX ring.

In these two cases, the buffer are allocated by the `dev_alloc_skb()`. I would like to just allocate the `skb` control header only and point the `data` pointers to my message buffer. We also have to modify the `skb_free()` to put the message buffer back to the message pool instead.

May anyone please tell me if there are any reference code which also uses the similar approach or please propose a better approach that minimize code change. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: I am also trying to solve a similar problem, what approach did you took?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40857686/mapping-1-mib-of-reserved-memory-for-network-interface-cardnic-driver-in-arm-l

Answer (score 0):

You could use [build_skb](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/104156/):

> So the deal would be to allocate only the data buffer for the NIC to
>   populate its RX ring buffer. And use `build_skb()` at RX completion to
>   attach a data buffer (now filled with an ethernet frame) to a new skb,
>   initialize the `skb_shared_info` portion, and give the hot skb to network
>   stack.
>
> `build_skb()` is the function to allocate an skb, caller providing the
>   data buffer that should be attached to it. Drivers are expected to call 
>   `skb_reserve()` right after `build_skb()` to let `skb->data` points to the
>   Ethernet frame (usually skipping `NET_SKB_PAD` and `NET_IP_ALIGN`)